# How do I format a combobox in order to display a selection but abbreviate that selection after its made?

Tags: excel, vba

I have loaded a combobox with all the states in the union with their respective abbreviations...(example "Florida - FL").  And it shows this in this format when the user is selecting a state from this combo-box.  I want the user to see the state in this format but when the user selects the state, I would like the field to only read "FL" and not the entire name as stated before the selection is made.  So when the drop down activates you see the name but after selected only the abbreviation is displayed.  Please help.

I have tried field formatting

I want the user to see the state in this format but when the user selects the state, I would like the field to only read "FL" and not the entire name as stated before the selection is made.  So when the drop down activates you see the name but after selected only the abbreviation is displayed.

Comment: Interesting problem. You can use a `Change_Event` of some sorts and then change the displayed text to `Right(Combobox, 2)`. I'm not sure if this will preserve the drop down though. What if they click the wrong state? I'm not sure what it will look like when they go back in without writing out all the code myself so you can test this and see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the states are in two columns, first column the abbreviation, second column the full name. Set the following properties for the combobox:

- BoundColumn: 2 (or 1 if you want the linkedcell to receive the
  abbreviated state name)
- ColumnCount: 2
- ListSource: A1:B55 (or wherever your states are    located)
- ColumnWidths: 30;100

Now if the dropdown is "dropped" you see both abbreviation and full state name. If the state is chosen, it only displays the abbreviation.